# VueJS: Error - Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have some issues in my Vue Code I want to create a ScrollToTop Button in Vue but I get this Error message in console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

**My Code :**

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isExample: false,
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  },
  methods: {
    handleScroll() {
      if (window.scrollY > 120) {
         this.isExample = true,
         $('.example-1').addClass("is-close"),
      } else if (window.scrollY < 120) {
         this.isExample = false,
         $('.example-1').removeClass("is-close")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The error is telling you that you are using jQuery widouth the importing the library.. using jQury inside vue is not the right way to go

Comment: Read about data binding fore vue

Comment: There is really no reason why you’d want to use jQuery with VueJS.

Answer (score 0):

Try to import `jQuery` in the component, or define `$` globally in your application:

```
import $ from 'jquery'
```

Also, you can do this in `js`:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('example-1')
```

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off topic/bad questions! [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572)

Comment: @double-beep OP is trying to use ``jquery`` in their ``vue`` application, so the problem is  different than that marked as duplicate to